# How to create variables based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In the below code, I need to create two variables, namely flag1 and flag2. They are created based on multiple conditions. I used np.select approach as below. However, I wonder what would be the other ways to do this? In my real work situation, there would be more conditions to create the flag. Any advices or suggestions would be great.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2020-04-01'
end_date = '2020-05-01'

d1 = {'customer type':['walk in', 'online app', 'phone app', 'referral'], 'office visit': 
['location1','location1','location1','location1'],'date1':['2020-04-17','2020-05-17','2020-03- 
01','2020-05-01'],'date2':['2020-05-18','2020-04-18','2020-04-03','2020-05-19']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

con1 = [ (df1['date1'] >= start_date ) & (df1['date1'] < end_date )]
result1 = ['yes']
df1['flag1'] = np.select(con1, result1)

con2 = [ (df1['date2'] >= start_date ) & (df1['date2'] < end_date )]
result2 = ['yes']
df1['flag2'] = np.select(con2, result2)
```

Comment: kindly add the expected output

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The issue is I am not able to copy and paste any text to this website using company computer. I had to type all these codes in my personal laptop which doesn’t have python installed. The output would be two more columns flag1 and flag2 are added to the dataframe df1, value is yes for those rows which meet the conditions and 0 for those do not meet the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary and dynamically update the keys to the variable names and add the corresponding value of the variables.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2020-04-01'
end_date = '2020-05-01'

flags = dict()


flag_string = 'flag'

# This creates the strings flag1 and flag2 automatically
for i in range(1, 3):
    # concatenate the flag_string with the index of the loop
    flags[flag_string + str(i)] = flag_string + str(i)

print(flags)

d1 = {'customer type': ['walk in', 'online app', 'phone app', 'referral'], 
      'office visit':  ['location1','location1','location1','location1'],'date1':['2020-04-17','2020-05-17','2020-03- \
01','2020-05-01'],'date2':['2020-05-18','2020-04-18','2020-04-03','2020-05-19']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

con1 = [ (df1['date1'] >= start_date ) & (df1['date1'] < end_date )]
result1 = ['yes']
df1[flags['flag1']] = np.select(con1, result1)

con2 = [ (df1['date2'] >= start_date ) & (df1['date2'] < end_date )]
result2 = ['yes']
df1[flags['flag2']] = np.select(con2, result2)
```

This is how you can substitute dictionary values as variables. I've also included a for loop that builds your flag dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @CobraPi for the ideas. May I ask how can I make flags[“flag1”] and flags[“flag2”] the variables in my dataframe df1?

Comment: I've added an example of what I think you're asking. Are you talking about `df1['flag1']`? Because if you are, that's not a variable, that's an index

Comment: Oh , I didn’t know df1[‘flag1’] and df2[‘flag2’] are index but not variable. Thanks for the information. But, is there any straightforward way to create variable based on multiple conditions? In SQL, it’s easy to create calculated field using case when condition1 and condition2 then result end as new_variable. Is it that hard to accomplish the same thing in python ?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean by 'create a variable based on multiple conditions'?

Comment: df1[‘flag1] and df1[‘flag2’] are the new variables I need to created in the dataframe df1 based on multiple conditions.

Comment: I think I’m referring to using if then else concept to create new columns within a dataframe. I found examples in the below website. However, most of these approaches appear to work for only one condition(criteria). 

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-if-then-else-in-python-the-way-you-work-in-sas-3ccbda30ce8b